# golang code insert/substitute

Tags: go, go-templates

I like not to allow the code to repeat. But I have a situation, when I must repeat it in every function I want to measure execution time, and I can do nothing to it.
For example, a function:

```
func someFunc() {
    start_time := time.Now()
    defer fmt.Println("Execution time: %v", time.Now().Sub(start_time))
    <... doing some bussiness ...>
}
```

Now I must repeat this two first strokes in every function (and in original they are more complicated because of calling a function name). So I cannot make a function which measures time, because i must use defer inside of it. I cannot make a function even for second stroke, cause in original it calls a function name in Println and that's why the resulting name will not be of needed function.
Is there any way to insert this code by some label or a template, for example, like this:

```
func someFunc() {
//go-insert measuretime.tmpl
    <... doing some bussiness ...>
}
```

And measuretime.tmpl is:

```
start_time := time.Now()
defer fmt.Println("Execution time: %v", time.Now().Sub(start_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

This trick might help: defer a call to a function returning a function enclosing the start time.

```
func elapsed() func() {
    start := time.Now()
    return func() {
        fmt.Println("Duration was", time.Since(start))
    }
}
```

Call it as follows:

```
defer elapsed()()
```

[Have a play](https://play.golang.org/p/xpD3Pnb3Pk)

Having said that, benchmarking is the usual way to measure performance in Go. See [how to write benchmarks in Go](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go).

Comment: Ye, it works, thx. Not exactly like I want, but still. And still I am interested in code insertions be cause of avoiding of inner functions calls. In this case it's unnamed function in return func().